# retrieve Name instead of ID by inner joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables one for employee and one for ticket. On the ticket table, I can see the id of the person that has built a code, also the id of the person that has validated the build. And I can get the full name of the person using the employee table. Now, I want to get the distinct number of the tickets for a specific time frame that either builder or validator equals a specific person. The following picture shows a part of my employee table:

[image]

Also, here is the code that I wrote:

```
select distinct(t1.ticketid),
  t1.BuilderAnalystID,
  t1.VALIDAnalystID,
  t2.EMPFullName
from Ticket as t1
inner join employee as t2 on t1.BuilderAnalystID=t2.EmployeeID 
where  (t1.builderanalystid=7 or t1.VALIDAnalystID=7) and
StatusID <>12 and
cast(BuildCMPLTDT as date)>= '2017-09-01'
and cast(BuildCMPLTDT as date)< '2018-04-01'
```

but I could only see the full name of the builder, how can I see the full name of the validator, even though the validator or builder are different people.

Comment: We really need some complete sample data and expected results to be able to assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
select distinct(t1.ticketid),
  t1.BuilderAnalystID,
  t1.VALIDAnalystID,
  t2.EMPFullName,
  t3.EMPFullName As Validator
from Ticket as t1
inner join employee as t2 on t1.BuilderAnalystID=t2.EmployeeID
inner join employee as t3 on t1.VALIDAnalystID=t3.EmployeeID  
where  (t1.builderanalystid=7 or t1.VALIDAnalystID=7) and
StatusID <>12 and
cast(BuildCMPLTDT as date)>= '2017-09-01'
and cast(BuildCMPLTDT as date)< '2018-04-01'
```